# How do I wait for slot content to render?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

Hi I don't know what to call this problem, or if it's supposed to be like that for a reason.. but is there any way for me to wait for slot content to render?

Basically I have a component which I want to know whenever it is scrollable or not, the content of the outer wrapper `#bit-box` is being rendered through a vue slot...

The problem is the `isScrollable` function always returns false, even tho it has overflow and is scrollable when the page is fully rendered... If I run the same function `isScrollable` in the console when everything is loaded it will return `true`...

The content I put into the slot is available directly from the controller in the beginning of the page load, no ajax or anything funky to load the slot data.

Scroll Function

```
export function isScrollable(ele){
    return ele.scrollHeight > ele.clientHeight;
}
```

Component (BitBox)

```
const bitBox = shallowRef<HTMLDivElement>();

onMounted((): void => {
    if (typeof bitBox.value === 'undefined'){
        return;
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // This actually never triggers
        alert('WE ARE READY');
    });

    if(isScrollable(bitBox.value)){
        alert('Scrollable Yeeeah 1');
    } else {
        alert('Scrollable Naaah 1');
    }

    if(isScrollable(document.getElementById('bit-box'))){
        alert('Scrollable Yeeeah 2');
    } else {
        alert('Scrollable Naaah 2');
    }
});

<template>
    <div
        ref="bitBox"
        id="bit-box"
    >
        <slot name="content"></slot>
    </div>
</template>
```

Some random component that uses the `BitBox`

```
<template>
<BitBox>
    <template #content>
        <p v-for="someData in dataset" :key="someData">
            {someData.title}
        </p>
    </template>
</BitBox>
</template>
```

It is frustrating because the `isScrollable` function works, but it looks like it triggers before the data is there.

Comment: is `dataset` a `static` data or as `async` data ( come from API for example )

Comment: It comes directly from the controller, and is available immediately, no async or anything

Comment: Could you reproduce the issue in a live code editor like `codesandbox` with any data?

Comment: Try nextTick, it's intended for cases without async ops

Comment: @Mina does not look like codesandbox works well with composition API :)

Comment: @EstusFlask Moving the stuff into an async function with nextTick worked :D a bit meh... but I guess that will do :)

Comment: Shouldn't be necessarily async, just nextTick with a callback. It's perfectly legit for race conditions that are related to rendering

Comment: @EstusFlask ohhhh, I see, that is really really cool... This will help me quite a bit actually, now I can also get the contents and determine the correct height programmatically of let's say x number of grid rows, wow thank you so much